# Select MIN() in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, min

I already wrote this sql statement to get person id, name and price for e.g. plane ticket.

```
SELECT Person.PID, Person.Name, Preis
FROM table.flug Flug
INNER JOIN table.flughafen Flughafen ON zielflughafen = FHID
INNER JOIN table.bucht Buchungen ON Flug.FID = Buchungen.FID
INNER JOIN table.person Person ON Buchungen.PID = Person.PID
WHERE Flug.FID = '10' ORDER BY Preis ASC;
```

My output is correct, but it should only be the line with min(Preis).

If I change my code accordingly, I get an error...

```
SELECT Person.PID, Person.Name, min(Preis)
FROM table.flug Flug ...
```

As output I need one single line: PID, Name and Price whereas Price is the min(Preis).

Comment: If its the `min(Preis)` for all rows, then drop the `Person.PID, Person.Name` from the Select List as they have no meaning, or if you want a min(Preis) per person, add `Person.PID, Person.Name` to a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You need `GROUP BY Person.PID, Person.Name`

Comment: table.something is just a placeholder for a username within the database...

Comment: try to filter in  the where clause  like `WHERE preis = (select min(preis) from ...)`

Comment: thanks everybody. it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already sorting your lines, just add a `limit` clause:

```
SELECT     Person.PID, Person.Name, Preis
FROM       table.flug Flug
INNER JOIN table.flughafen Flughafen ON zielflughafen = FHID
INNER JOIN table.bucht Buchungen ON Flug.FID = Buchungen.FID
INNER JOIN table.person Person ON Buchungen.PID = Person.PID
WHERE      Flug.FID = '10' 
ORDER BY   Preis ASC
LIMIT      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group your result by `Person.PID` and `Person.Name` in order to select these fields in the same query where you're using aggregate function `min()`.

```
SELECT Person.PID, Person.Name, min(Preis) as Preis
FROM table.flug Flug ....
WHERE Flug.FID = '10'
GROUP BY Person.PID, Person.Name
ORDER BY 3 ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the query is returning the result you want correctly, but you are getting more rows than you want, you can add a **`LIMIT 1`** clause following the `ORDER BY`.

If you want to get just a single line for each unique combination of `Person.PID` and `Person.Name`, then add a `GROUP BY` clause before the ORDER BY clause, and use `MIN()` aggregate around `Preis` in the `SELECT` list.